# Achieve Json result to list

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, json

```
 public class Child
    {
        public int ids { get; set; }
        public string names { get; set; }

    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public int ids { get; set; }
        public string names { get; set; }
        public List<Child> children { get; set; }
    }
}
```

From above  how we can achieve the result for my Json to render

```
[
        {
            id: 1,
            names: 'root1',
            children: [
                { id: 2, name: 'child1' },
                { id: 3, name: 'child2' }
            ]
        },

    ];
```

my Local variable creating an instance.
What is going on, the application connection to a folder. depending on how many files it loops through.
The problem is I cannot return the above structure in children correctly. kind of stuck and know I am missing something small.
Can anyone make example to achieve these result, not link to websites.

```
var attachmentsList = new List<RootObject>();
FileInfo[] files = dinfo.GetFiles();

                foreach (FileInfo file in files)
                {

                    attachmentsList.Add(new RootObject
                    {
                        id = i + 1,
                        name = "Folder" + i + 1,
                        children = new List<Child>(
                            id = i + 1,
                            file.Name
                        )

                    });
 i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to iterate over the files in each selected directory :

```
var attachmentsList = new List<RootObject>();

FileInfo[] files = dinfo.GetFiles();
var rootObject = new RootObject {  
                                    id = 1, 
                                    name = "Folder1", 
                                    children = new List<Child>()
                                };

foreach (FileInfo file in files)
{
      rootObject.children.Add(new Child { id = i + 1, file.Name });
      i++;
}

attachmentsList.Add(rootObject);
```

Comment: Ok but id says  child does not contain a definition for id